# Updating from such a repository can't be done securely

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 19.04 it results in:

```
Err:1 http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
  Could not connect to lt.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (193.219.61.87). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to lt.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:778::87). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:2 http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease              
  Cannot initiate the connection to lt.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:778::87). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Get:3 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease [2,590 B]                    
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease               
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Ign:7 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
Get:8 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release [986 B]
Get:9 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty/main amd64 Packages [564 B]
Get:10 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release.gpg [481 B]
Get:11 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty/main i386 Packages [564 B]
Get:12 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Packages [831 B]
Reading package lists... Done     
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I cannot install any program with `sudo apt-get install`. How can I fix this situation?

Comment: The mirror you're using is down, at least via IPv6.  I'mma relay this to the MIrrors team for them to take a look.  Switch your mirrors to archive.ubuntu.com in the inteirm.

Comment: Two of the errors look like PPAs that do not have packages for your release of Ubuntu. Disable those PPAs.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

First, you have a PPA that is 404ing, which means it doesn't support Disco.  You need to disable that (it's the GNOME3 team's GNOME3 PPA).

Secondly, the mirror on `lt.archive.ubuntu.com` at `193.219.61.87` (IPv4) and `2001:778::87` (IPv6) might be having problems. <sup>*</sup>

You may wish to change your mirrors in `/etc/apt/sources.list` temporarily to use `archive.ubuntu.com` - the central Archive mirror - to get your updates for now.

<sup>* NOTE: I'm going to send this to the Mirrors Team for them to look at, but given this is a holiday weekend there may not be rapid movement on this.  This has been filed in Ubuntu's RT tickets system as #33540</sup>

Comment: I solved the first problem thanks to you. but unfortunately in second problem, I changed the `deb http://lt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main`  the mirror with yours `archive.ubuntu.com`  but it didn`t work out. did I changed the correct thing ?

Comment: I would need to see what you changed.  Chances are you didnt edit the lines right.

Comment: Thanks to you the problem is solved.