# Manually Installed and Compiled Package Breaks apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa

I've installed ksuperkey via cloning from git and compiling with make. Now when I run "apt update" it has an error:

```
username@osboxes:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                        
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                      
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mehanik/ksuperkey/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                  
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mehanik/ksuperkey/ubuntu bionic Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mehanik/ksuperkey/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
username@osboxes:~$
```

I don't care to update this ksuperkey item and want to just "apt update" everything else.  I found a similar posting ["What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) that I got to through [Updating from such a repository can't be done securely [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146176/updating-from-such-a-repository-cant-be-done-securely). And I tried to ppa-purge the mahnik/ksuperkey, but that hasn't worked:

```
username@osboxes:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:mehanik/ksuperkey
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mehanik/ksuperkey/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
username@osboxes:~$
```

In summary, How can I get rid of this "mahanik/ksuperkey doesn't have a Release file, Can't update from securely" error to ensure my "apt update" works?

Comment: Try `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mehanik/ksuperkey` followed by `sudo apt update`

Comment: You clearly tried at least two methods of install: 1) A PPA and 2) Compiling from source. The error output indicates that the PPA is dead. This suggests that you did not remove the PPA, perhaps after attempting to use it failed. So, of course, correcting that oversight and removing the PPA fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked. It had a "press enter to remove" confirmation which I did then "sudo apt update" worked and all packages are up to date.

> Try `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mehanik/ksuperkey` followed by `sudo apt update`
> – Archisman Panigrahi

Thanks!